# Check if value exists while iterating with *ngFor - Angular 10

Tags: angular, ngfor

I populate a *mat-select* by iterating on two arrays:

```
<mat-select>
     <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of groups; trackBy: trackGroup" [label]="group.name">
       <ng-container *ngFor="let question of group.questions; trackBy: trackQuestion">
         <mat-option [value]="question._id">
            {{question.title}}
         </mat-option>
       </ng-container>
   </mat-optgroup>
</mat-select>
```

I want to check if a given question id is in the list without iterating all over again in the controller ts file. If it doesn't exist I want to apply a class to a div outside of the mat select. Something like this:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'warning': !exists}">
    <mat-select>
        ...
    </mat-select>
</div>
```

How can I do this? I thought I could do it in the trackBy function but it seems the component variables are not yet defined.